# Execute statement only returns #Rows

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, prepared-statement

I'm using PMA to test some pivot queries (dynamic columns), everything seems to be working just fine however, I'm only getting the # Rows in my results, not the actual set of rows.

How can I see my result set?

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(t.week_end = ''',
      t1.week_end,
      ''', t.st_hours, NULL)) AS ''',
      t1.week_end, '\''
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM timesheets t1 WHERE t1.week_end > "2015-03-01";

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT t.assignment_id
                    , ', @sql, ' 
                   FROM timesheets t
                  LEFT JOIN timesheets t1 ON t.timesheet_id = t1.timesheet_id
                   GROUP BY t.assignment_id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Returns `# Rows: 440`

`SELECT * FROM table` - Returns the actual set of rows

Comment: can we... see the statement?

Comment: @dgig I don't think the statement has anything to do with it. If I copy the statement and run it as a static query I get results. When EXECUTED via prepared statement and user defined variable I only get Row Count

Comment: Well @dgig is right we need to see what statement is... Or whole stored procedure would be even better. Your prepare stmt syntax only missing semicolon at the end that's only thing I can see here missing...

Comment: @AleksandarMiladinovic ok there's the rest of the statement but like I said, the statement is fine. I just can't figure out how to get PMA to return the actual result set when using PREPARED->EXECUTE rather than your standard, static query

Comment: I just worked with prepared statement and yours look just OK it should return results from SELECT statement as expected. I'm not smart enough to see what's wrong here. Only problem may be in first part Select Group_Concat(Disti... INTO sql. Can you try to just instead that Select statement set something simpler as 't1.week_end' and then see what's happened? Debug step by step exclude one part first... Hope someone will come with solution. GL

Comment: I don't think you understand, this is not a syntax issue, this is a PHPMYADMIN issue. my query is fine. PMA is just showing me the number rows in the result set, rather than the actual result set. It must be due to the use of the prepared statement and EXECUTE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No Results in PHPMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34201964/no-results-in-phpmyadmin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be resolved in the latest PHPMyAdmin builds, and should be released in version 4.6.

> [Prepared statements] can be sent in query as this pretty much works in phpMyAdmin right now. The only problem is displaying results. If you execute all of above, you get result just from last query (DEALLOCATE), which shows 0 rows, but if you do it without DEALLOCATE, you reportedly get 1 row, but it's not displayed.

[Reference](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11741)