# No Results in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

This with the Mysql Console:

```
set @Name=CONCAT('seq_0_to_',DATEDIFF('2015-12-15','2015-12-05')-1);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> set @s =CONCAT("SELECT DAYNAME('2015-12-05' + INTERVAL (seq) DAY) day,'2015-12-05' + INTERVAL (seq) DAY date FROM ",@Name);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared

MariaDB [test]> EXECUTE stmt;
+-----------+------------+
| day       | date       |
+-----------+------------+
| Saturday  | 2015-12-05 |
| Sunday    | 2015-12-06 |
| Monday    | 2015-12-07 |
| Tuesday   | 2015-12-08 |
| Wednesday | 2015-12-09 |
| Thursday  | 2015-12-10 |
| Friday    | 2015-12-11 |
| Saturday  | 2015-12-12 |
| Sunday    | 2015-12-13 |
| Monday    | 2015-12-14 |
+-----------+------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

In PMA I get only:

```
 # Datensätze: 10
```

but no results like the console gives me.

Why ?

Comment: Apparently, you are not alone with this issue, however, no answers there either. Could be a bug in phpmyadmin or a setting. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29240965/phpmyadmin-execute-stmt-only-returns-rows

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue in phpMyAdmin which was fixed in version 4.6.0: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11741